# python - TypeError: unorderable types: str() > float()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

i have a csv file and has v3 column but that column has some 'nan' rows.
How can i except the rows.

```
 dataset = pd.read_csv('mypath') 

    enc = LabelEncoder()
    enc.fit(dataset['v3'])
    print('fitting')
    dataset['v3'] = enc.transform(dataset['v3'])
    print('transforming')
    print(dataset['v3'])
    print('end')
```

Edit: V3 columns has A,C,B,A,C,D,,,A,S, like that,and i want to convert it to (1,2,3,1,2,4,,,1,7)

Comment: Could you show your csv file content?

Comment: What do you want to to with these rows? Drop them? (`dropna`) Fill the NaN values? (`fillna`)

Comment: no,i want to this row categorize to numbers.That row has characters.

Comment: Can you add sample of your data? Maybe 5-6 rows and desired output. Or better [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you mean `pandas.factorize`?

Comment: V3 columns has A,C,B,A,C,D,,,A,S, like that,and i want to convert it to (1,2,3,1,2,4,,,1,7)

Comment: What should happen to the nan's in that column?

Comment: nothing,because of this i am getting this error TypeError: unorderable types: str() > float()

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mask the nan values by using ~isnull():

```
mask = ~dataset['v3'].isnull()
dataset['v3'][mask] = enc.fit_transform(dataset['v3'][mask])
```

Another way is to use the pandas.factorize function, which takes care of the nans automatically (assigns them -1):

```
dataset['v3'] = dataset['v3'].factorize()[0]
```

Comment: thanks a lot:) dataset['v3'] = dataset['v3'].factorize()[0] solved my problem