# apriori model has TypeError: unorderable types: float() < str()

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

[mydataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Va2yI.png) i imported all the libraries correctly but unable to get a list of rules and it shows this "TypeError: unorderable types: float() < str()"

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("Market_Basket_Optimisation.csv", header = None)
transactions =[]
for i in range(0,7501):
      transactions.append([str(dataset.values[i,j]) for j in range(0,20)])

#training of dataset
from apyori import apriori
rules = apriori(transactions,min_support=0.003,min_confidence=0.2,min_lift=3,min_lenght=2)
res= list(rules)
```

i got this error on execution of last line

Comment: `transactions` is a list of strings. Shouldn't it be a list of integers or floats instead?

Comment: Please check the datatype for each column in your dataset 'dataset.dtype()' since you're importing without specifying the dtype.

There are similar questions in the related links on the right hand side.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310710/python-typeerror-unorderable-types-str-float?rq=1

Comment: dataset consists of string type only. It consists of all the market products bought by customers. i just edited my question with the dataset