# Unorderable types: str() < float()

Tags: python

I was asked to write a python script by defining some variables and display all the objects defined in the current namespace by using the 'dir' function. And here is my program for the above problem.

```
a = 10
b = 3.14
s = "Hellow"
x = True
class any:
    def __dir__(self):
        return[a,b,s,x]
my_obj = any()
print(dir(my_obj))
```

But I am getting error as

> unorderable types: str() < float()

Please help, Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310710/python-typeerror-unorderable-types-str-float/35311558

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`dir` function returns sorted list. So all the elements which you return should be of same data type in order to get it sorted.

In you example you are passing elements of different data type so ```dir()`` is unable to sort it.

**And don't use python keywords(like any, sum, list) as class name or function name**

Comment: Is solution is correct with respect to problem statement ?

Comment: Check the solution

Comment: Its working fine and according to my understanding of problem the answer is write but when i write it in Web Based Training window its replying it as a wrong answer

Comment: Don't use python keywords as class name or variable name.

Comment: yes I have changed that and answer is correct but I want you to interpret the problem statement and what we are trying is right ?

Comment: In order to use dir() you need to keep all variables i.e. a,b,s,x of same data type

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__dir__), `dir` sorts the keys returned from `__dir__`, so they have to be comparable. Moreover, as the function intention is to return [names](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir), they all should be strings.

As for your assignment, just calling `dir()` without arguments already returns all the names defined in the current namespace.